# Dynamically Create Meteor Handlebars Template Helpers?

Tags: templates, internationalization, meteor, handlebars.js, meteorite

I have a list of i18n translation strings within an meteor-i18n object that I'm iterating over. Instead of creating a Template Helper for each string manually though, which would soon become redundant and repetitive, I would like to create the Helpers dynamically, within a loop, like so:

```
for (var namespace in Meteor.i18nMessages) {
  for (var msg in Meteor.i18nMessages[namespace]){
    //Template[namespace][msg] = __(namespace + "." + msg); // <- works but is not reactive
    Template[namespace][msg] = function() { // <- Doesn't work: always returns last value from object
      return __(namespace + "." + msg);
    }
  }
}
```

However when I do, I lose reactivity. How would one go about solving this? I'm a fan of best-practices and elegant code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to precompile the handlebars templates with

```
Meteor._def_template("templateName", function () { 
    return "your html"
});
```

This creates a template at `Template.templateName` which will be reactive with the helpers defined for it.

EventedMind has some screencasts that show how this works in good detail:

- http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/handlebars-how-it-works
- http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/handlebars-precompiling

Comment: Thanks. Tried this in the client, however no dice Meteor._def_template("lang.language", function () {
  console.log("Hola!");
  return "Text in Spanish";
});

Comment: I just tried this and it works. (note you can't use a `.` in the template name it has to be a standard object key (letters,numbers,underscore). For instance I tried your same one with 'lang' and I got a new template at Template.lang

Comment: OK, gotcha. I'm still defining the templates in HTML, so for example I've got <template name="lang">{{language}}</template> and <template name="footer">{{translatedfootertext}}</template>. What I want to do is to update the hundreds of translated strings dynamically in different templates across the site. Do I have to create all of the templates in JS?

Comment: You could use one of the packages on atmosphere to help you out like this one: https://github.com/txgruppi/meteor-simple-i18n

Comment: Thats a slightly different one but the basic principle remains the same. You need to pass the strings down using template helpers e.g `Template.hello.lang = function() {return Sesson.get('translatedMessage')}`

Comment: That's what I was doing, however the problem was I didn't reactivity to work creating the template helpers in a loop. Which was what I was asking. I've now posted a version that works (but is ugly).

Answer (score 0):

My text editor keeps calling me "evil" for using eval but this works:

```
for (var namespace in Meteor.i18nMessages) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var msg in Meteor.i18nMessages[namespace]) {
    var str = 'obj["' + msg + '"] = function() { return __("' + namespace + '.' + msg + '"); }';
    console.log(str);
    eval(str);
  } 
  Template[namespace].helpers(obj);
}
```